# How to configue working copy in SVN?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have to check out an existing SVN repository of **40 GB**

The SVN is exposed over HTTP and transfer rate is very slow(20 KB / Sec).

So I got the working copy through an external hard disk. Now, How do I tell the copied version to synchronize with the SVN repository ?

I'm using Tortoise SVN.

Let me know for further information.

Answer (score 3):

If you copied the whole sandbox (all files including all .svn directories) you just have to rightclick and update. If this doesn't work, use the tortoisesvn-relocate command on the base directory and specify the url of the repository. Then try again updating.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response.
I tried tortoisesvn - relocate option but it errors out saying the UUID is different.

Old URL: svn+ssh://99.99.99.99/files/svn/xyz/trunk/abcd
New URL: https://office-backup.abc.com:8443/svn/xyz/trunk/abcd

Can you please help?

Comment: This really should not happen. The most probably reason for this is the url you specified pointing to the wrong repository. The repository has a unique id and there is no way that it _accidently_ changed. Use the the tortoisesvn repository-browser, navigate to that url and check if you're really connecting to the right repository.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the working copy has been create from the same repository, a simple `svn update` will do. Tortoise should also recognize the directory as a working copy.